# Rails Show in controller not saving updated User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a show method in my Users controller that changes the values of User through api calls.

It isn't saving this data when I change pages through.

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ...
  p @user.year
  @user.save
```

Interestingly @user.year shows what I want, but the next time I load a page, the value for @user.year is back to nil. Am I missing something. Thanks

Comment: show your model , may be is some event is binded with  after or before save.

Comment: how are you updating the user model? are you using update_attribute or update_attributes?

Answer (score 1):

In the code in your question, you're not changing anything before you save. E.g. this should change the `year` value:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.year = 1942
  @user.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use that:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```